# SonarQube 7.0 - Two modules have the same id: ''. Each module must have a unique id

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I am trying to set up sonar for my Hybris project to scan my code and I am using java 8 and sonarqube 7.0. I use ant commands.
When I run ant sonar, I get the following error
....resources/ant/sonar.xml:89: Two modules have the same id: ''. Each module must have a unique id.

I see that this is called from sonar-scanner jar file but I am not sure what is causing this

Answer (score 0):

Each project and module must have a unique id within SonarQube. You don't specify whether your project is multi-module or not, but since you're using Ant, I know you've manually defined your analysis properties. Comb through them to make sure each `sonar.projectKey` value in this project is unique - both within the project and across your SonarQube instance.

Comment: Hello Ann thanks for the response. I have defined sonar.projectkey in sonar.xml <macrodef name="sonarmultiJAVA">

  <attribute name="modules"/>

   <sequential>

    <property name="sonar.extensions" value="@{modules}" />

    <property name="sonar.sourceEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>

    <property name="sonar.projectName" value="xxx"/>

    <property name="sonar.projectKey" value="xxx" /> I am getting the error even after. Like I said, I have gone thru all configurations. Hence the reason on why I am unclear on the cause

Comment: ` <property name="sonar.projectKey" value="xxx" />`? You appear to have a hard-coded key value in your macro definition.